# SQL Server: How to improve performance for queries with multiple CTEs and subqueries in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

I have the following two tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE Portfolio.DailyPortfolio
    (
    BbgID varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Ticker varchar(22) NULL,
    Cusip char(9) NULL,
    SecurityDescription varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    AssetCategory varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    LSPosition char(3) NULL,
    Ccy varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    Quantity int NULL,
    AvgCost decimal(7,3) NULL,
    PriceLocal decimal(7,3) NULL,
    Cost int NULL,
    MktValNet int NULL,
    GLPeriod int NULL,
    Beta decimal(4,2) NULL,
    BetaExpNet int NULL,
    BetaExpGross int NULL,
    Delta decimal(4,2) NULL,
    DeltaExpNet int NULL,
    DeltaExpGross int NULL,
    Issuer varchar(48) NOT NULL,
    Country varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Region varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Sector varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Industry varchar(48) NOT NULL,
    MktCapCategory varchar(24) NULL,
    MktCapEnd int NULL,
    Date date NOT NULL,
    PortfolioID  AS BbgID+LSPosition+ Convert(varchar(8),Date,112) Persisted Primary Key
    )
    GO
```

Here is the second table:

```
    CREATE TABLE Portfolio.DailyStats
    (
    Date date NOT NULL Primary Key,
    NAV int NOT NULL,
    SP500 decimal(8,4) NULL,
    R2K decimal(8,4) NULL,
    NetExp decimal(8,4) NULL,
    GrossExp decimal(8,4) NULL,
    )
    GO
    ALTER TABLE Portfolio.DailyStats
    ADD [YrMn] as  CONVERT(varchar(7), Date)
    GO
```

Between 80-100 rows get added to the DailyPortfolio table every business day (the table has about 32,000 rows currently). 1 row gets added to the DailyStats table every business day (it has about 500 rows currently). The Date column in the Daily Portfolio table has a Foreign Key relationship with the Date column in the DailyStats table.

I had to create a view that included a few columns from both tables using last quarter as the date range. The last column of this view uses the Average of the NAV column in its calculation where the Average is calculated by using the NAV on the 1st date of each of the 3 months in the quarter. Here is my DDL for the view:

```
    CREATE VIEW Portfolio.PNLLastQTD
    AS
    WITH CTE1
    AS
    (
    Select Date, NAV,YrMn, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YrMn ORDER BY Date) AS Row
    FROM Portfolio.DailyStats

    WHERE DATE BETWEEN 
        (SELECT Convert(date, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,GETDATE()) -1 ,0)))
    AND
        (SELECT Convert(date, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,GETDATE()),0))))
    ),
    CTE2
    AS
    ( 
    SELECT  AvG (NAV) As AvgNAV
    FROM CTE1
    WHERE Row=1
    )
    SELECT IssuerLS, Issuer, Ticker,  SUM (GLPeriod) As [PNL],
        CAST(SUM(GLPeriod)As Decimal (13,2)) /  CAST(CTE2.[AvgNAV] As Decimal (13,2)) as [%ofNAV]
    FROM Portfolio.DailyPortfolioIssuerLS ls
    JOIN cte2 on 1=1
    WHERE ReportDate 
    BETWEEN 
        (SELECT Convert(date, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,GETDATE()) -1 ,0)))
    AND
        (SELECT Convert(date, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,GETDATE()),0))))
    GROUP BY 
        Issuer, Ticker, IssuerLS, CTE2.[AvgNAV]
    GO
```

The view works fine but takes almost 20 seconds to execute! I have a couple of questions here:

1. Should there be some changes made to my DDL for the view?
2. Is it a good idea to create a non-clustered index on the date column (if at all possible) of the DailyPortfolio table?
3. Is there anything else I should be thinking of to improve query performance for this particular issue?

Thanks much for your help. Please forgive blatant mistakes as I'm new to SQL.

Comment: Id post this on dba.stackexchange.com and codereview.stackexchange.com though you may find helpful answers here too.

Comment: You can probably improve performance by having proper indices on the tables involved in the query. Analyze the execution plan in SSMS, it will probably suggest some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to close on the loop on this question. What I needed to do here was create two non clustered indices. I used the following steps:

1. Placed my query on the query window.
2. Clicked on "Display Estimated Execution Plan" button on my toolbox which immediately informed me of a missing non cluster index.
3. Created the first non-clustered index:

   ```
   USE [OurDB]
   GO
   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_DailyPort_Issuer_Date
   ON [Portfolio].[DailyPortfolio] ([Issuer],[Date])
   GO
   ```
4. Repeated step 2 and created the second non-clustered index as recommended:

   ```
   USE [OurDB]
   GO
   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_DailyPort_Date_INC_DexpN_Issuer
   ON [Portfolio].[DailyPortfolio] ([Date])
   INCLUDE ([DeltaExpNet],[Issuer])
   GO
   ```

The query now takes less than 3 seconds to execute, significantly better than the 24 seconds it was taking before this.

Note: If you right click on the line that informs you about the missing index, you can choose an option to see the code for the index which saves you time.